# How to create a Grid and set RowDefinitations with FrameworkElementFactory in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use `FrameworkElementFactory` to create a grid template, but how to define its `RowDefinition`s ?

as the code

```
FrameworkElementFactory gridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
FrameworkElementFactory RowDefinitionFactory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(RowDefinition));
gridFactory.AppendChild(RowDefinitionFactory1);
FrameworkElementFactory RowDefinitionFactory2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(RowDefinition));
gridFactory.AppendChild(RowDefinitionFactory2);
```

it will throw exception...

because the `<RowDefinitation>` should be under `<Grid.RowDefinitations>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has been deprecated:

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates,
>   which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or
>   DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when
>   you create a template using this class. The recommended way to
>   programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a
>   memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.

The suggested route is to use `XamlReader.Load` or `XamlReader.Parse` if you need to programmatically create templates.

```
var template = 
    "<Grid>" +
        "<Grid.RowDefinitions>" +
            "<RowDefinition/>" +
            "<RowDefinition/>" +
        "</Grid.RowDefinitions>" +
    "</Grid>";

var markup = XamlReader.Parse(template);
```